# Can mspec tests run in the native Visual Studio 2010 test runner?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mspec, test-runner

I have mspec running with R#, but my client doesn't have R# and doesn't plan on getting it. :( I want my test suite (written completely with mspec) to be valuable to my client, so it would be HUGE if the VS2010 test runner ran specifications written with mspec. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running MSpec in the VS runner is not possible. You can set up MSpec as an external tool that runs the current assembly in a separate console window (free), have your client purchase TestDriven.Net or convince him to invest in ReSharper (I'm sure we both agree the tool is worth its price :).

Comment: Absolutely worth the price. However, when trying to convince a client to embrace and maintain a test suite, it's important to me to remove as many obstacles and as much friction as possible. Would it be possible after some extension or modification to mspec or would it just not be possible at all?

Comment: I have no idea if the VS test runner is extensible in any way, so it might be possible or not. What one could try is add MSTest wrappers around MSpec contexts but these would have to be generated dynamically from the compiled MSpec assembly, possibly using Reflection.Emit and somehow forcing VS to load the generated MSTest assembly. I would consider that a hack, and a nasty one I might add.

Comment: You might want to look into AutoTest.Net. It's more of an automatic test runner that looks for file changes, recompiles and runs tests using mspec.exe (or any other framework for that matter). It's free (OSS), but I don't know about its VS integration.

Answer (score 0):

MSpec is supported by other productivity tools as well. TestDriven.Net has already been mentioned, but if your client already uses Telerik JustCode or DevExpress CodeRush then it should be no problem to test the specifications from within Visual Studio.